# Does UILabel's lineBreakMode only make sense when numberOfLines is not 1?

Tags: swift, uilabel, ios9

Does UILabel's lineBreakMode only make sense when numberOfLines is not 1? It seems like there won't be any line break will there is only one line of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `NSLineBreakMode` specifies modes other than wrapping which apply to single lines such as beginning or end of text truncation. See the docs at

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@NSLineBreakMode